# Unable to preselect value on select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using this library
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.js">`

I know there are a lot of examples out there and I've tried them all most recent:

```
var $client_id = $("#client_id").select2({
                dropdownParent: $('#categoryForm'),
                ajax: {
                    quietMillis: 300,
                    url: apiPath,
                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: true
                    },
                    crossDomain: true,
                    type: "GET",
                    data: function (params) {
                        var queryParameters = {
                            search: params.term
                        }
                        return queryParameters;
                    },
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                            results: $.map(data.data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    text: item.client_name,
                                    id: item.client_id
                                }
                            })
                        };
                    }
                }
            });

            $client_id.val(6).trigger('change');
```

As you can see at the bottom I'm trying to select the value using the (valid) ID. I have been successfull using this method:

```
        var option = new Option(data.customer_name, data.customer_id, true, true);
        customerSelect.append(option).trigger('change');
```

But I'd rather just use the ID if it's possible